# Showing twice html

Tags: php, html, handler, stack-trace

So I'm making an error handling for my site. I want to be able to activate the error handler by using

> include_once("errorhandler.php");

so far it works great, it display the error if an error occurs, however I'm facing another problem. I've made a php file called "test.php", that looks like this:

```
<?php
include("errorhandler.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My awesome page :D</h1>
        <?php
            mysql_connect("test","test");
            opendir("test");
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now the issue is that, the error is display but the header is also shown, since it gets to execute that part, before the script crashes and starts the error handler.

It makes the page look like this:
[image: Image of the error]

Basically, I need the error handler to clear everything before it writes the Html.

I've tried using `<script> document.write('');</script>`

In the start of my error handling method, with no luck.

So now I'm stuck with this, any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: look at the PHP manual for output buffering.

Comment: Thank you, used ob_clean(); It works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `ob_clean();`
In the start of the error handler, so when it occured it would clean the page!

Answer (score 0):

put die(); after the include that'll stop the rest of the page running either that or wrap an if around your exception so `if (exception) { //do include } else { //show normal code }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your html in a function:

```
public function render() {
    $this->ht_content = '<html> Your html </html>';
    return $this->ht_content;
}
```

Then in your error handler you can say something like this:

```
if($errors) {
    // Error stuff here
} else {
    $ht = new html();
    $ht->render();
}
```

you can make this as big and nice as you want :)